How to combine the PROP of a list of PROP in lean 4?
I have the following structures:
structure MyElem where
  identifier : Nat
  acceptable : Prop

structure MyList where
  elements : List ( MyElem )

I want to create a predicate for MyList returning a Prop being the conjunction (i.e. and) value of all MyElem.acceptable Prop in MyList. Something like:
def acceptable ( l : MyList ) : Prop :=
    e1.acceptable and e2.acceptabe and ...

I am struggling to find the proper syntax in Lean 4 as the documentation is incomplete for List.

Perhaps you could explain what you're doing because it sounds like you're using lists to encode a finite map Nat → Prop, and that's unlikely optimal. Pleaes explain the big picture.

If you are willing to use Mathlib, you can use List.Forall:
import Mathlib.Data.List.Defs

def List.AllProp (l : List Prop) : Prop :=
  l.Forall (fun x => x)  -- need Mathlib.Data.List.Defs

#check [True, False, True].AllProp  -- Prop

Otherwise, it is easy to make your own with foldl, recursion, or treating a list like a set.
def List.AllProp2 (l : List Prop) : Prop :=
  l.foldl (init := True) (. ∧ .)

#check [True, False, True].AllProp2  -- Prop

def List.AllProp3 : (l : List Prop) -> Prop
| [] => True
| p :: l => p ∧ l.AllProp3

#check [True, False, True].AllProp3  -- Prop

def List.AllProp4 (l : List Prop) : Prop :=
  ∀ (p : Prop), p ∈ l → p  -- Or more compactly: ∀ p ∈ l, p

#check [True, False, True].AllProp4  -- Prop

One advantage of using List.Forall is that there are theorems about it already like List.forall_cons:
example : [True, False, True].AllProp = False := by
  unfold List.AllProp
  /-
  ⊢ List.Forall (fun x => x) [True, False, True] = False
  -/
  simp [List.forall_cons]

Further, functions which output Prop are not computable, so if you want this for programming, then it is better to use Bool.  There is List.all in core Lean.  Moreover, common decidable propositions automatically coerce into Bool.
def List.allBool (l : List Bool) : Bool :=
  l.all (fun x => x)

#eval [1 == 1, 0 < 2, 3 ≤ 1].allBool  -- false
#eval [1 == 1, 0 < 2, 3 ≥ 1].allBool  -- true


def List.allBool2 (l : List Bool) : Bool :=
  l.foldl (init := true) (. && .)

#eval [1 == 1, 0 < 2, 3 ≤ 1].allBool2  -- false
#eval [1 == 1, 0 < 2, 3 ≥ 1].allBool2  -- true


def List.allBool3 : (l : List Bool) -> Bool
| [] => True
| p :: l => p ∧ l.allBool3

#eval [1 == 1, 0 < 2, 3 ≤ 1].allBool3  -- false
#eval [1 == 1, 0 < 2, 3 ≥ 1].allBool3  -- true

For finding what is already in Lean or Mathlib, I have found https://www.moogle.ai helpful.
Finally, for your particular use case:
structure MyElem where
  identifier : Nat
  acceptable : Prop

structure MyList where
  elements : List ( MyElem )

def acceptable ( l : MyList ) : Prop :=
    l.elements.Forall MyElem.acceptable

But depending on your use case, I think it is more likely you want MyElem.acceptable to be Bool not Prop.  (Then use l.elements.all instead.)

Thanks for your detailed explanation. I thought about using Bool, but in my case, Prop corresponds perfectly to my use case. I must refrain from 'coding' in Lean since I am really about creating a proof. I am new to the game...

@JérômeVerstrynge I see that mathematicians tend to avoid programming in proof assistants, but it is by embracing the idea that programming and writing proofs are two points of view of the same, underlying, concept, that you can become proficient with Lean. It is easier for a mathematician to learn the proof point of view first, as that is probably the most familiar one, but you should not refrain from changing perspective when it is more fit.
